# Why does my adapted Selection Sort algorithm not work in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

I have code for selection sort which I wrote over a year ago in Python [here](https://repl.it/@NormyHaddad/Selection-sort#main.py), But when I tried to adapt it to C++ it just stopped working completely, and the algorithm, which is logically exactly the same, sorts the algorithm differently and prints out a mess.

```
void SelectionAscending2(int array[], int numItems)
{
    int count;
    int temp;
    int minimum;
    int Pass = 0;
    //while (Pass < numItems)
    for (int i = Pass; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        count = Pass + 1;
        minimum = Pass;
        //while (count <= numItems)
        for (int j = count; j <= numItems; j++)
        {
            if (array[count] < array[minimum])
            {
                minimum = count;
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        temp = array[Pass];
        array[Pass] = array[minimum];
        array[minimum] = temp;
        Pass += 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << ", ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[8] = { 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7 };

    int length = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);
    SelectionAscending2(myArray, length);
}
```

This code works perfectly fine in python, but in C++ it outputs this instead:
`2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7,` 
I've been struggling with this for 3 days now and nothing I've done has worked.

Comment: The for loops you have created are not exact replacements of the while loops in python code.

Comment: I tried using while loops, but nothing was printed to the console even after waiting a couple minutes, so I was forced to use for loops

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Yes, I did try changing them a bit, but they still didn't work. Unless the syntax is wrong I have no idea what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have diverted a bit from the python code.

- In the python code you have set the `length of array (numItems)`
  to `actual length - 1` but here you have put the `length (numItems)` same as the `actual length`.
- And also while printing you are printing from i = 1. So that's why
  your code is not working as expected.

So you can do these changes (one of the ways):

1. Change `j <= numItems` in second for loop to `j < numItems`
2. While printing the array using the last for loop, start from i = 0